# How to solve java.lang.StackOverflowError in MVC design pattern (plus mySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC design pattern, and I'm a complete beginner in design pattern and java.
If I didn't put the LoginModel login = new LoginModel()); java.lang.nullPointerException will pop up. But when I put it, this java.lang.StackOverflowError happens.
I'm not sure if I give enough details, but if you need more, just mention, I'll provide more details..

```
public class LoginModel {

    private String userName;
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;
    Timer timer;

    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    LoginModel login = new LoginModel(); //this is where the error happens


    public LoginModel(){}
    public LoginModel(int id,String userName,String email){
        this.id=id;
        this.userName=userName;
        this.email=email;        
    }

    public int getID(){
        return id;
    }
    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }


    public void setStartTime(long time){
        startTime=time;
    }
    public void setEndTime(long time){
        endTime = time;
    }
    public long getUsedTime(){
        return (endTime-startTime);
    }
    public LoginModel(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new LoginModel.RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
    }
    public void setTimer(int seconds){
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new LoginModel.RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
    }



    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "60 seconds left!");
            timer.cancel();

        }
    }



    public void RetrieveDbase (Connection conn){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE username = ? and password = ?";
    String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM admin_info WHERE username = ? and password = ?";
    String sql11 = "SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE username = ? and password = ? and paidRemainingTime != 0";

    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome "+jTextField1.getText());
            try{
                 pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql11);
                 pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
                 pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
                 rs = pst.executeQuery(); 
                 if (rs.next()){ 

                    new dummyHomepage().setVisible(true);
                    //this.setVisible(false);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Paid Time Remains "
                             + rs.getInt("paidRemainingTime")+"Minutes");                     
                    login.setTimer(rs.getInt("paidRemainingTime"));
                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis( );
                    login.setStartTime(startTime);

            }

                 else{

                     new PurchaseInterface().setVisible(true);
                     //this.setVisible(false);

            }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

        }
        else

             try{
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                    pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome ADMIN "+jTextField1.getText());
            new ManageUserInterface().setVisible(true);
             //this.setVisible(false);
            }
            else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid username and password");    
            }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    }
     catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    }

    public Connection getDbase(){
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursive `new LoginModel()`. You have an instance field `LoginModel login`. When you create a new `LoginModel, it creates a new LoginModel, ad nauseam.

Answer (score 1):

Your call `LoginModel login = new LoginModel();` produces a `StackOverflowError` because it's recursive.  When you attempt to create a `LoginModel`, it creates another `LoginModel` for the  `login` instance variable, which creates another `LoginModel` for *its* `login` instance variable, and so on.

What is the purpose of the `login` instance variable?  If it's just to remove the `NullPointerException`, then it's not working.  It's just covering it up.  Remove it and try something else to debug the `NullPointerException`.

The cause of the `NullPointerException` is probably because neither of these instance variables are ever set in your code.

- jTextField1
- jTextField2

Answer (score 1):

```
LoginModel login = new LoginModel();
```

`login` is a member variable in this case, which means that it'll be created for every new object of the type `LoginModel`.

Since creating a `LoginModel` object creates the member variable `login` which is a `LoginModel`, which creates a member variable `login` which is a `LoginModel`... you have a problem.